# How to change the image url in svg using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-svg

I want change image url dynamically based id attribute  using jquery below i given the svg tag. any one help me.

```
<image id="background_image" width="804" height="943" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" style=" pointer-events:none;background-repeat:repeat-y;" xlink:href="http://www.example.com/img/imag.png">
```

i want change dynamically  the blow url
http://www.example.com/img/imag.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple selector with `attr` like the one below should work for you.

```
$('#background_image').attr('xlink:href','newurl.com/image.png');
```

Comment: What if you had multiple dynamic images (after using AJAX) that you like to convert to SVG? How can you convert those images to SVG?

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to update the `href`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#background_image').attr('xlink:href', 'http://placehold.it/350x150');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<image id="background_image" width="804" height="943" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin" style=" pointer-events:none;background-repeat:repeat-y;" xlink:href="http://www.example.com/img/imag.png">
```